# Authentication failed on the server Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

Всем привет.
Сроный вопрос. У меня есть приложение, которое отлично работает на эмуляторе, да и на телефонах с скомпилированным apk. Я выпустил проект в гуглмаркет. Скачал с маркета и воаля.Карта не грузится:

`E/b: Authentication failed on the server.
E/Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
E/Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
                                                            Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
                                                            Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
                                                                API Key: ********
                                                                Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): ****;com.***.***`

Comment: я нашел тут такои ответ
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32373602/authentication-failed-on-the-server-google-maps-api-android
суть ее я понял, мол разные ОС. но блин.как мне сделать ключ для всех??я же не могу несколько ключей делать?да и как мне сделать под всех.
кто подсобит?

Comment: в общем собрав всю инфу, которая все же довольно крыво изложена(по моему мнению даже на оф сайте) нужно делать 2 типа лицензий, для релизной версии и для версии дебажной.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=ru

тут есть коды для этого(переключайте закладки в зависимости от нужного типа ключа)

 а ключи можно как в манифесте , так и в грандле залить.я в монифест залил

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны использовать `sha1` ключ того же компьютера, на котором собираете релизную версию для выкладывания в Play Market.

Плюс Вы должны учесть, что ключи для `debug` и для `release` также разные.